# Is there any api for pubnub?

Tags: pubnub

I want to work on personal project working with instant messaging. I was wondering if there were any APIs like pubnub that are open to the public.

thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can find all the open source API's and tutorials at http://www.pubnub.com/developers

You can also find a tutorial on building an instant messaging like application at http://www.pubnub.com/blog/ditch-your-backend-with-pubnub-messenger/

*Full disclosure I am a PubNub employee*

Answer (score 0):

All the PubNub SDKs and the APIs are open source and public. You can choose your favorite language and start coding by looking at [Developer Resources and Docs](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/). There are several examples for [Building A Basic Chat Application | PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com/solutions/chat/) itself.

Comment: Links tend to change or go missing, could you explain some of the contents or quote it here?

Comment: [Developer Resources and Docs](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/) provides in depth API documentation for over 70 SDKs, quickstarts to give you a quick guide on how to include PubNub in your program and to use the APIs, and also access to the community and the developer console. All these tools will help you get PubNub running in a matter of minutes.


[Building A Basic Chat Application | PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com/solutions/chat/) takes you through the process of building a real time mobile chat using a lot of tutorials and step by step guides.

Answer (score -2):

I think that a solution for your issue is [openpush](http://openpush.im/).